# How can the display name of measurements be directly set in Cumulocity/Java

Tags: java, cumulocity

I want to send `MeasurementValues` to `Cumulocity` and visualize the data with the given tools. Which values are sent by my software is specified in a JSON and has to be changeable after compilation.

**My issue:**

The Java `Cumulocity` Framework doesn't allow me to specify the Name of the measurement fragment that will be displayed on their Website. The name is always the class name of the `POJO` I used to create the measurement. Since I want to send many different variables (which ones will also change over time), it isn't viable to just create many POJO classes beforehand.

**My question:**

How can I - sending measurements from one class - display different values in `Cumulocity` with different names using the Java `Cumulocity` Framework?

**What I tried so far:**

- There is no measurement property that allows me to change the displayname
- There is no way to change a class name at runtime (it's compiled ^^)
- The Cumulocity Java Framework doesn't give me direct access to the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand which name of a measurement you want to change, but I'm assuming you mean the name of the measurement fragment.

When you have created a custom measurement in your Java project you have the possibility to annotate it with ***@Alias*** to provide your custom name

```
package c8y.tinkerforge.measurements;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.svenson.AbstractDynamicProperties;
import org.svenson.JSONProperty;

import com.cumulocity.model.measurement.MeasurementValue;
import com.cumulocity.model.util.Alias;

@Alias("c8y_Acceleration")
public class AccelerationCombinedMeasurement extends AbstractDynamicProperties {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2491579656609755745L;

    public static final String DEFAULT_UNIT = "g";

    private final String unit;

    private MeasurementValue accelerationX;

    private MeasurementValue accelerationY;

    private MeasurementValue accelerationZ;

    public AccelerationCombinedMeasurement(double accelerationX, double accelerationY, double accelerationZ,
            final String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
        this.accelerationX = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationX), unit);
        this.accelerationY = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationY), unit);
        this.accelerationZ = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationZ), unit);
    }

    @JSONProperty("accelerationX")
    public MeasurementValue getAccelerationX() {
        return accelerationX;
    }

    public void setAccelerationX(double accelerationX) {
        this.accelerationX = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationX), unit);
    }

    @JSONProperty("accelerationY")
    public MeasurementValue getAccelerationY() {
        return accelerationY;
    }

    public void setAccelerationY(double accelerationY) {
        this.accelerationY = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationY), unit);
    }

    @JSONProperty("accelerationZ")
    public MeasurementValue getAccelerationZ() {
        return accelerationZ;
    }

    public void setAccelerationZ(double accelerationZ) {
        this.accelerationZ = new MeasurementValue(new BigDecimal(accelerationZ), unit);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((accelerationX == null) ? 0 : accelerationX.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((accelerationY == null) ? 0 : accelerationY.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((accelerationZ == null) ? 0 : accelerationZ.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AccelerationCombinedMeasurement other = (AccelerationCombinedMeasurement) obj;
        if (accelerationX == null) {
            if (other.accelerationX != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!accelerationX.equals(other.accelerationX))
            return false;
        if (accelerationY == null) {
            if (other.accelerationY != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!accelerationY.equals(other.accelerationY))
            return false;
        if (accelerationZ == null) {
            if (other.accelerationZ != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!accelerationZ.equals(other.accelerationZ))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AccelerationCombinedMeasurement [accelerationX=" + accelerationX + ", accelerationY=" + accelerationY
                + ", accelerationZ=" + accelerationZ + "]";
    }

}
```

In this case it should use the name c8y_Acceleration. When I create a datapoint graph for a sensor which uses this measurment class you get this:

[image: name is red outlined]

You can see the name in the red outline.